# AWS Chaining Lambda Functions with SNS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I have two lambda functions that should be triggered when an object is uploaded to an S3.

To trigger both scripts, In the first script I am publishing a sns topic that is followed by the second script. When publishing it I should pass the event so that I can manipulate it.

I am having issues passing the event to the second lambda function. Here is how I am doing it:

First script passes the event like this

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
 console.log("Loading metadata function");
 var eventText = JSON.stringify(event, null, 2);
 console.log("Received event:", eventText);
 var sns = new AWS.SNS({region:'us-west-2'});
 var messageparams = {
    Message: eventText, 
    Subject: "Successfully send",
    TopicArn: "MyArn"
 };
 sns.publish(messageparams);
```

Second Script Should use the event like this

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    """
    :param event:
    :param context:
    """
    # Loop through records provided by S3 Event trigger
    for s3_record in event['Records']:
        logger.info("Working on new s3_record...")
        # Extract the Key and Bucket names for the asset uploaded to S3
        key = s3_record['s3']['object']['key']
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you [configure S3 to publish events straight to SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)  without any intermediate Lambda. Next, you can configure two or more Lambdas to be [invoked by the SNS notifications](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html).

On the flip side, if you only need a single Lambda function, you can configure S3 to publish events and [invoke the Lambda with the event data as parameter](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html) directly without SNS involved.